# Can file object called from decorator to wrapped function?

Tags: python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I want to call the file object from decorator to the wrapped function . may codes as below :

```
from functools import wraps
checkresultfile = './test.txt'
def log_detection_res(detect_items = ''):
  def process_reminder_decorator(check_func):
      @wraps(check_func)
      def addingReminder(*args, **kwargs):
          process_begin_reminder = "=" * 10 + detect_items + "start" + "=" * 10
          process_stop_reminder = "=" * 10 + detect_items + "end" + "=" * 10
          with open(checkresultfile, 'a') as res_file:
              res_file.write(process_begin_reminder + '\n')
              check_func(*args, **kwargs)
              res_file.write(process_stop_reminder + '\n')
          return check_func(*args, **kwargs)
      return addingReminder
  return process_reminder_decorator

@log_detection_res(detect_items = 'filter odd')
def print_odd(array_a):
    for _ in array_a:
        if _ % 2 == 0:
            checkresultfile.write(_)

filter_dd = print_odd([1,2,3,4,5])

out_put

  line 21, in print_odd
    checkresultfile.write(_)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

The error comes due to `checkresultfile` is a `str` not `file object`, the error parts can be fixed by as below :

```
def print_odd(array_a):
    with open (checkresultfile, 'a') as f:               
        for _ in array_a:                 
            if _ % 2 == 0:                
                f.write(str(_))
```

I don't want ot use `with open ... as ...` in the wrapped function but call the  `res_file` in decorator , is that reliable in such situation ?

Answer (score 0):

Below way works：

```
from functools import wraps
checkresultfile = './test.txt'
def log_detection_res(detect_items = ''):
  def process_reminder_decorator(check_func):
      @wraps(check_func)
      def addingReminder(*args, **kwargs):
          process_begin_reminder = "=" * 10 + detect_items + "start" + "=" * 10
          process_stop_reminder = "=" * 10 + detect_items + "end" + "=" * 10
          with open(checkresultfile, 'a') as res_file:
              res_file.write(process_begin_reminder + '\n')
              #adding a key parameter to refer to file object res_file in decorator 
              check_func(output_file = res_file, *args, **kwargs)
              res_file.write(process_stop_reminder + '\n')
          return check_func
      return addingReminder
  return process_reminder_decorator

@log_detection_res(detect_items = 'filter odd')
def print_odd(array_a, output_file):
    for _ in array_a:
        if _ % 2 == 0:
            output_file.write(_)

filter_dd = print_odd(array_a = [1,2,3,4,5])
```